# Having some issues with 9patch image

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

I am trying to make a chat bubble. So I tried to make a 9 patch image, But it's not getting auto stretched.
So here is my 9 patch image ,

**[Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B03fOf9LvEyFZWFwQXpDVTBsTWc)**

And here is my XML file of the chat bubble..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bubblee"
    >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxWidth="300dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            tools:text="lol" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how the current chat bubble looks,

[Chat bubble image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXbvg.png)

I think I never made any 9 patch image before, so the problem is with the 9 patch image, tell me if i made any mistake :(

Thank you :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kept already a lot of width for your image so by default it will take that much width.

try to make small image from width and then check it if it works or not

Comment: So there is no problem with the 9 patch ?

Comment: yes there is no problem but decrease the width it will auto stretch according to text length.

Comment: Ohk I will try.. Thanx

Comment: Tried decreasing the width to 100 .. But no luck :( . I have to make it more smaller?

Comment: Just try to make it to 50-70px and also make top and bottom black line same or remove the top black line

Comment: I tried for 50px... And it's working.. But not decreasing the width.. So it means, We can only increase the 9 patch image size? So everytime i have to make the image according to minimum width requirement